# Angular - Import * as $ from 'jquery' for all components

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Is there somehow a way to avoid this import in every component, and make it global for all components?

`Import * as $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: you can add jquery in you angular.json under scripts (remember to pick the min version from node_modules. then you can use jquery. However you still need to declare $ else typescript wont recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Angular components and modules are written in Typescript files as a module using export keyword. As we build our Angular application to the greater extend, we end up creating many feature modules and components. We can refer a component or a module in other using “import” statement. Without “import” Typescript compiler shall throw exception for unknown type. Same goes for external imports. However, it would be possible to minimize this list of imports by importing such libraries to a seperate file `index.ts`. However the `index.ts` would still have to be imported to the component.

Other option would be to to add jquery to `angular.json` and import it via scripts.

```json
 "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  ]
```

Install the typings files you need.

```
npm i -S -D @types/jquery
```

Now you don't need to `import * as $ from 'jquery'`. That would duplicate imports, which is bad. Instead access methods directly.

```
ngOnInit() {
   const $h1 = $('h1');
   $h1.css('color', 'blue');
 }
```